# What causes playing a video in browser to take up all the RAM?

Tags: macos, video, memory, performance

I've been noticing lately that when I'm playing a video on my Mac from say Hulu, Netflix, Youtube, any video site via a browser, the computer gets extremely laggy for 5 minutes and then acts normal. I've looked at my activity monitor icon, and its showing that during that short period the RAM is being maxxed out.

Mac Mini with OSX v 10.9.2. Fusion Drive with SSD

It has 16GB of Ram, 2 Thunderbolt monitors and a Wacom Cintiq plugged in HDMI port.

Comment: Could you edit the version of OS X you run and perhaps a screen shot of activity monitor showing Memory - sorted by Real Mem descending?

Comment: You might look and make sure you have the newest version of flash https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ and silverlight http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx. Many browser plugins (e.g. flash, silverlight) are pretty terrible at playing video compared to other alternatives (e.g. iTunes, VLC).

Comment: I'm running the latest flash player version (i make flash games) and silverlight is up to date along with running google canary so I can get the latest bleed versions.

Comment: Woah - three displays on the Mini GPU might be a stressor that no amount of RAM can overcome. I think your Mini has a Intel HD Graphics 4000 and if you repeat the video play test with only one Display - does it improve the playback rates and lag?

Comment: I'll try it out and get back to you. But yeah, I think its the graphics card. Because I can't play 3d games on STEAM at all without the computer dying on me. And I just got the Mac Mini. :/

Comment: So, yeah I think it's because Im running three external monitors. But I tried testing it on just one and there's still some lag but not as bad. I think it's the graphics card :/

Comment: I've never seen this problem before. What you can try is updating your graphic's card.

Comment: Software problems are more desirable than hardware problems. Try a non-bleeding-edge browser, and see if the problem persists. I'd even go as far as running a fresh installation on a separate partition before I spend money on hardware.